# Linear KdV equation with $L^2$ initial data

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, solution-verification

**Problem:** The linear Korteweg-de Vries equation  in $[0,\infty) \times \mathbb R$ has the form
\begin{equation*}\begin{cases}\begin{aligned}
\left[\partial_t + \partial_x^3 \right] u(t,x) &= 0\\
u(0,x) &= u_0(x).
\end{aligned}\end{cases}\end{equation*}
Show that for each $u_0 \in L^2$, this equation admits a unique solution $u \in\mathcal C[\mathbb R;L^2]$.

**My Approach:** I will use the following definition of the Fourier transform
$$\widehat f(\xi)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{d/2}}\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(x)e^{-ix\cdot\xi}\,dx.$$
Now taking the Fourier transform of the equation in the space dimension yields
$$\widehat{u}_t(t,\xi)-i\vert\xi\vert^3\widehat u(t,\xi)=0,$$
which is an ODE in the time variable. The solution of the ODE can be found by using integrating factors, and is given by
$$\widehat u(t,\xi)=e^{it\vert\xi\vert^3}c(\xi).$$
Applying the initial condition we get that
$$\widehat{u_0}(\xi)=\widehat u(0,\xi)=e^{i0\vert\xi\vert^3}c(\xi)=c(\xi).$$
So the unique solution to the ODE is given by
$$\widehat u(t,\xi)=e^{it\vert\xi\vert^3}\widehat{u_0}(\xi).$$
It follows that the unique solution of the equation is given by
$$u(t,x)=\mathcal F^{-1}\left\{e^{it\vert\xi\vert^3}\widehat{u_0}(\xi)\right\}(x).$$
Since $\left\vert e^{it\vert\xi\vert^3}\right\vert=1,$ the Plancherel theorem implies that
$$\|u(\cdot,x)\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)}=\|\widehat{u_0}\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)}=\|u_0\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)}<\infty,$$
and hence the equation admits a unique solution which is in $L^2(\mathbb R)$ for all $t\in[0,\infty).$

---

Do you agree with my approach above?
Thank you for your time and feedback.